# Through javascript decrease amount in a box and increment the same value decrease to another box dynamically

Tags: javascript

Here is a sample idea.

`Amount - discount = amount` paid by the customer.

But the customer pay less and the box `due` need to be increment dynamically.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Server should handle all monetary calculations.

Comment: Have you tried breaking this into smaller tasks?  Like, 1. getting the value from a form box. 2.  Adding/subtracting. 3.  Putting the newly calculated value back into the form box.  Or did you think there was a command that did exactly everything you wanted in one step?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version of what I believe you're asking for:

**HTML**

```
Price: <input type="text" id="tb-price" />
Discount (%) <input type="text" id="tb-discount" />
Total: <span id="lbl-total" />
```

**Javascript (jQuery required)**

```
$(function(){
    // vars
    var $tbPrice = $('#tb-price');
    var $tbDisc = $('#tb-discount');
    var $lblTotal = $('#lbl-total');

    // events
    $tbPrice.on('input', calc);
    $tbDisc.on('input', calc);

    // calculation
    function calc(){
        var x = $tbPrice.val() * ($tbDisc.val() / 100);
        var y = $tbPrice.val() - x;
        $lblTotal.html(y);
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zkhx1z1d/

Do note that there is no validation here and assumes that the user input is clean. Also this should only be used to show the user what they expect to pay, all calculations should be done/verified by the server as suggested by AlienWebguy